# Bootstrap navigation include

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, include, navbar

I have the following bootstrap navbar. I want to include nav.php into all of my php pages. Well I have done simple includes in the past but with `div` tags something tells me I am doing this wrong.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
          <div class="container-fluid">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt=" "></a> 
           </div>

           <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <?php include 'nav.php';?>                
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
   </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
 </nav>
```

My nav.php is as following

```
               echo'
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
               <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
               <li><a href="itsupport.html">TEAM</a></li>
               <li class="dropdown">
                 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">SERVICES <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                 <li><a href="itservices.html">IT SERVICES</a></li>
                 <li><a href="voiceservices.html">VOICE SERVICES</a></li>
                 </li>
                 </ul>
                </li>
                      <li><a href="careers.html">CAREERS</a></li>
                      <li><a href="careers.html">INTERESTING INFORMATION</a></li>
                      <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                      </ul>';
```

Comment: ok, I found it and edited the post.  NOW the question makes sense.

Comment: Does the nav.php file start with `<?php` ?

Comment: Sorry I am new to this system. It just doesn't display the code all the time. I had to indent

Comment: yes it does and end with ?>

Comment: There is a markup error-- there's an extra `</li>` after Voice Services.   But it will probably still render.   If you view-source of the html after, does anything show up in source code?  If it does, its a css hide problem.  If it doesn't, the include itself isn't working... probably a bad path or php isn't executing.  Do you have other php scripts?

Comment: That </li> is from the dropdown. I don't think it is extra

Comment: Well I think you are right about the </li> sorry

Comment: Terrible mistake from my end I feel st.pid :)

Comment: I have been editing my index.php file in another folder.

Comment: Why `echo '';` ? Why not just have HTML in your file to include with no `<?php ?>` tags... Also try with `require()` to make sure it's finding the file. See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dkxepr5y/ - it's showing up with your HTML as needed so it's obviously a PHP location or syntax error. Do you have PHP error reporting on? http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

Answer (score 0):

Two possible paths:

Add `<?php` tag to your nav.php file,
or
remove `echo` statement and make the file plain HTML.